# What does `tail -F -c +0` mean?

Tags: shell

`tail -F -c +0 call.log`

I have know that `-F` means monitor `call.log` as it changes.However,what does `-c +0` mean here? Are `-c` and `+0` working together or seperately?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a site I loved from the first glance [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com)

[image]

Comment: Shame it gives slightly misleading answer (the bit about 10 lines) ...   -c +0 means dump the whole file (not last 10 lines), and THEN -F means keep dumping as it grows.

Comment: A bit misleading because it explains each argument separately, agree. But you also have `-c +0` argument explained

Comment: So cute, and so useless. In that it doesn't e.g. tell what `--follow=name` does, or how those options interact with each other.

Comment: @ikkachu blame the man page for that .. which is what this is derived from isn't it @Mike?

Answer (score 1):

`tail` prints the tailing part of the file, 10 lines by default. With `-f`, it keeps the file open after this, and "follows up" on it, printing any new contents as it appears. With `-F`, it doesn't follow the open file descriptor, but repeatedly checks for the file by *name*, in case the underlying file changes by way of being renamed or recreated.

The `-c +0` tells it to output the file *starting at* byte 0 (because of the plus), so the whole file. And in combination with `-F` it continues following the file name after this.

So the effect is to print the whole file, then follow up on any new contents on the same file, or another that afterwards take the same name.

See the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) for the individual options, and try e.g.,

```
$ seq 10 > file.txt
$ tail -c +0 -F file.txt
```

and from another window:

```
$ echo hello > file.txt
```